# Read link of xml file within and xml file and keep parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, youtube, sax

I am parsing an xml file using sax parser. The xml file contains link to another xml file in link tag with next attribute. I have to keep on reading until the last xml file that do not have next attribute.
Following is the xml file:

```
   <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EokUNzGJBI8/comments" />
   <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EokUNzGJBI8/comments/batch" />
   <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EokUNzGJBI8/comments?start-index=1&amp;max-results=25" />
   <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EokUNzGJBI8/comments?start-index=26&amp;max-results=25" />
```

I have tried the following:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
boolean content=false;   
int i=0;
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Content")) {
        content = true;
        i+=1;
    }
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Link") && attributes.getValue("rel").equalsIgnoreCase("next")){
        l=attributes.getValue("href");

        u=true;
    }   
}
```

To recursively read the url returned above in `l` i do the follwoing:

```
saxParser2.parse(new InputSource(ur.openStream()), handler);//to read original url
 while(l!=null)
 {
     urs=new URL(l); //successive urls
 saxParser.parse(new InputSource(urs.openStream()), handler);
 }
```

The above keeps on printing the last response after it cannot find next in last xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : Hum, I'm sorry, I finally get your code.

In fact, you're not really doing recursive call, because you're calling parse in the second loop (while), which is a better idea.

So you should create a subclass of DefaultHandler, and let 'nextUrl' be an attribute of this class. So the code is :

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private String nextUrl;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // (...)
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Link") && attributes.getValue("rel").equalsIgnoreCase("next")){
            nextUrl=attributes.getValue("href");
        }   
    }

    public String getNextUrl() { return nextUrl; }
}
```

Then in your calling code :

```
String url = "*firstUrl*"; //ur=initial xml link
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
MyHandler handler = new DefaultHandler()
while(url != null){
    saxParser.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()), handler); 
    // Here, you'll certainly want to do something with the data loaded in handler...
    url = handler.getNextUrl();
 }
```

Comment: That means I can loop on this saxParser2 while calling reset?

Comment: @orabog Basically all I want to do is to read the href in link tag with rel="next" and parse it until the last xml file that will not have rel="next" attrib.